# Flutter: Disable a single button inside Listview after it is clicked once (ecommerce app)

Tags: flutter, button, flutter-listview

I have a small shopping screen and a cart screen application in which I want to disable the button inside the product list screen which consists of ListView.builder. I created a variable `List<bool> _isClicked = [false]`.
Below is the code for my Elevated button, I am not sure where I am going wrong and I am getting **RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1**. Please help me fix the problem. Thank you!

```
ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 8.0),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: productName.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
          color: Colors.blueGrey.shade200,
          elevation: 5.0,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Image(
                  height: 80,
                  width: 80,
                  image: AssetImage(productImage[index].toString()),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 130,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                      ),
                      RichText(
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'Name: ',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
                                fontSize: 16.0),
                            children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                      '${productName[index].toString()}\n',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            ]),
                      ),
                      RichText(
                        maxLines: 1,
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'Unit: ',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
                                fontSize: 16.0),
                            children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                      '${productUnit[index].toString()}\n',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            ]),
                      ),
                      RichText(
                        maxLines: 1,
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text: 'Price: ' r"$",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
                                fontSize: 16.0),
                            children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                      '${productPrice[index].toString()}\n',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.blueGrey.shade900),
                  onPressed: _isClicked[index]
                      ? null
                      : () {
                          setState(() {
                            _isClicked = [true];
                          });
                          dbHelper!
                              .insert(
                            Cart(
                              id: index,
                              productId: index.toString(),
                              productName: productName[index].toString(),
                              initialPrice: productPrice[index],
                              productPrice: productPrice[index],
                              quantity: 1,
                              unitTag: productUnit[index].toString(),
                              image: productImage[index].toString(),
                            ),
                          )
                              .then((value) {
                            cart.addTotalPrice(double.parse(
                                productPrice[index].toString()));
                            cart.addCounter();
                            print('Product Added to cart');
                          }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
                            print(error.toString());
                          });
                        },
                  child: Text(_isClicked[index] ? 'Added' : 'Add to Cart'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
```

Comment: provide the listview code also

Comment: @suzan i have updated my post and added the whole code

Comment: @suzan I have also added this line of code :     _isClicked = _isClicked.map((e) => false).toList();

Answer (score 0):

You have the variable set as `List<bool> _isClicked = [false]` and sets one item only.

but  when you are checking in the list item, the index is not in the list.
Example: if you check for the _isClicked value of item in index 3, it is not set in the `_isClicked` list as it has length 1.

so, the work around would be

1. when you get the productName, update the _isClicked list to have the same number of items as of the productName list.
2. Move the card widget into separate Stateful widget with its own isClicked boolean.

Comment: I understood the 2nd point you mentioned. But I am unable to understand the 1st one. Can you show me with an example please.